# react-hook-form reset errors messages only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup, react-hook-form

I have some dynamic fields, which gets removed/added on the basis of some hook state. I have fields which gets removed from the list but the errors for them are still visible. I have tried to `clearErrors, unregister` to remove it but nothing works.

is it possible? `reset` does work but it resets the whole form too.

I am using v6 of `react-hook-form` and i cannot upgrade it to 7. That's out of the picture for now.

`yup` validator is being used with it for validations.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck into the same problem seems like bug, if you try unregister the control it doesn't do it. Here how I have done.

When you remove the control do unregister and reset specific control.

```
 const handleRemoveRow = (control) => {
  //all code logic and stuff
  //................
  unregister(control);
  reset({ [control]: undefined });
};
```

After that on useEffect hook assume you have one main state of form, reassign the values back.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const keyValue = getValues();
    keyValues.map(({controlName,Value}) => {
      setValue(controlName, Value);
    });
  }, [getValues()]);
```

This is a more of pseudo-code but I hope you got the concept.